# How to start new activity fron android webview javascript interface

Tags: javascript, java, android, html

I'm working on android web application.

I want to start new activity from javascript.I googled and found a code to show toast.this is it.

```
    public class WebAppInterface {
            Context mContext;

            /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
            WebAppInterface(Context c) {
                mContext = c;
            }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

That code is working fine. but when I try to start new activity nothing happen.here is my code(sorry for bad english)

```
    public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Intent showAd = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ShowAd.class);
        startActivity(showAd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

In your javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function moveToScreen() {
        Android.moveToNextScreen();
    }
</script>
```

In your java code:

```
public void moveToNextScreen(){

                             //Move to Next screen
                             Intent newintent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondIntent.class);  
                             startActivity(newintent);  

    }
```

Add these in your onCreate

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        //Load URL inside WebView
        webview.loadUrl("Your html page url");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.But I want to start new activity from javascript function.not load some url on webview.